# Can I decrypt HDFS data while ingesting into HBase without having an intermediate decrypted file?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hbase

I am considering using HBase for my project. I have some encrypted files (they are encrypted at the file-level, not column-level or row-level encryption), and would like to store their decrypted contents into HBase. We are using Spark in our project.

Is there a way to ingest into HBase while decrypting the files so there is never an intermediate storage location that contains the decrypted files?

Since I do not **yet** have an installation of HBase to work with, I don't have any code that I've tried.

If this question is too broad, I can revise it. I was not sure how else I could frame the question without it being this broad.

Comment: Is there a way to ingest into HBase while decrypting the files, what do you mean and issue found could you please explain steps in question ?

Answer (score 0):

HBase does not have column-level encryption you can Encrypt HFile and WAL. You cannot encrypt/dcrypt only some columns, else use any of external tool

- https://www.protegrity.com/press-releases/protegrity-unveils-hdfs-based-file-encryption-technology/
- https://hortonworks.com/partner/dataguise/
- https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hbase.encryption.server